# How to match two successive EOL characters using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a text string in which double EOL separates a group of values.
e.g.:

```
aaa

bbb

ccc

ddd
```

I need to convert this string into the array of those values.
I tried:

```
 explode('\n\n', $string),
 explode(PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL, $string),
 preg_split('/\n+', $string) &
 preg_split('/\n\n', $string).
```

But it is not working.

Help please.

Comment: Is there any CR symbol there? Try `preg_split('/\R{2}/', $s)`.

Comment: perhaps the newline sequence of your string is `\r\n`? in this case use double quotes with explode.

Answer (score 1):

When you do not know newline sequences there are in the file and you need to match any, it is very convenient to use `\R` shorthand class with PHP regex that matches any newline sequence. Add a limiting quantifier `{2}` to match exactly 2 newline sequences:

```
'/\R{2}/'
```

See the [IDEONE code sample](https://ideone.com/YavIKE):

```
$s = "aa\r\n\r\nbb\n\ncc\r\n\ndd";
print_r(preg_split('/\R{2}/', $s));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => aa
    [1] => bb
    [2] => cc
    [3] => dd
)
```

In case there are more than 2 newline sequences, and you only want to split at exactly 2 newline sequences, use `'/(?<!\R)\R{2}(?!\R)/'`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, If you want to work with any php thing, please use double quotes.
\n will not be parsed as its in single quote therefore PHP will consider it as a normal string and not something to be parsed.

Try this:

```
$some = 'aaa

bbb

ccc

ddd';
$output = explode("\r\n\r\n", $some);
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `preg_match_all` like this:

```
preg_match_all ("/\S+/", $yourdata, $output_array);
```

[[Ideone Demo]](https://ideone.com/CyvWc4)

Note that with this solution your input data can have different number of new lines.